# SOQL query: What is the different between "1638369480000" and "1638369480000.0"

Tags: soql, query

An error occurred when I run this SOQL query.

```
SELECT long_number FROM some_table WHERE long_number <= 1638369480000
```

Error message:

> MALFORMED_QUERY:  some_table WHERE long_number <= 1638369480000
>
> ERROR at Row:1:Column:57 For input string: "1638369480000"

I solved the error by adding ".0" to the end of `long_number`.

```
SELECT Timestamp__c FROM IoTRM_FacilityLog__c WHERE Timestamp__c <= 1638369480000.0
```

Can anyone help me understand why adding ".0" can solve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOQL uses 32-bit signed integers, meaning the maximum integer value is 2,147,483,647.

SOQL doesn't understand long literals (e.g. something like `1638369480000L`). It'll complain about the 'L', and if you leave it out it'll try to treat it like an int.

By adding `.0` to the number literal, SOQL treats it as a `Decimal`, which can handle literals larger than 32 bits.

#### +edit:

Though if you're really trying to use a timestamp here, using a `Datetime` field instead of a `Decimal` would probably be a better decision.

You can get a Long timestamp (since unix epoch, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) by using the `getTime()` method, and turn a timestamp into a Datetime using `newInstance()`.

Comment: @Dreck Thanks for your help. The reason I saved the datetime as a number is because that it seems datetime does not keep milliseconds which is a must in my current project.